Verify if my proof that S ◦ R = ∅ iff Ran(R) and Dom(S) are disjoint is valid
I came across this problem from Velleman's How To Prove It.

Suppose R is a relation from A to B and S is a relation from B to C. Prove that S ◦ R = ∅ iff Ran(R) and Dom(S) are disjoint.

This is my initial proof although upon checking the solution, the author used proof by contraposition so I am not sure if my proof is valid. My question is I just want to know if my proof below is valid.

Let S ◦ R = ∅, then there does not exists any $b \in B$ such that $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in S$. Therefore the range of R and the domain of S does not have any common element. Thus Ran(R) and Dom(S) are disjoint.
Let Ran(R) and Dom(S) be disjoint. Then there is no $b\in B$ such that $b\in$ Ran(R) and $b\in$ Dom(S). Hence, there is no $b$ such that $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in S$. So S ◦ R = ∅.

Here is the proof of the author:


I just want to know if my proof is valid

Just edited it, thanks!

Overall your proof is correct. However, you're not explicit on which directions of the iff you cover. The author makes that clear, which helps the reader to understand the proof. Also, you write statements with $a,b$ without introducing those.
